# Advanced Tomato: 'Recent Web Searches' log always empty

Tags: wireless-router, logging, firmware, tomato, search-engines

The `Recent Web Searches` never worked. I tried with several different search engines (StartPage, DDG, Google, Yahoo) and never logs something.

[image]

I would like to enable that.

The `Recently Visited Web Sites` works fine, even requests with `curl`

Answer (score 3):

It logs only HTTP traffic. All search engines now use HTTPS.

I monitored my desktop's traffic with [ntopng](https://github.com/ntop/ntopng) and saw that all HTTPS traffic doesn't appear in Tomato logs.

> ntopng is a web-based network traffic monitoring application released
>   under GPLv3. It is the new incarnation of the original ntop written in
>   1998, and now revamped in terms of performance, usability, and
>   features.

I use for example a Twitter client which constantly streams via HTTPS. In Tomato logs no connection to Twitter visible.